# Using timer2's ISR instead of timer1's in Arduino wiring.c breaks Serial object

Tags: interrupt, timers

I want to change *timer0* frequency because I need to use 4 PWM pins at a frequency lower than 500Hz and the SPI on an ATmega328. So I changed *timer2* to *Fast PWM* with 64 divisor, enabled the overflow interrupt for timer2 and disabled the overflow interrupt for timer0:

```
  TCCR2A = _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
  TCCR2B = _BV(CS22);
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << TOIE2); // enable overflow interrupt for timer2
  TIMSK0 &= ~(1 << TOIE0); // disable overflow interrupt for timer0
```

and changed the ISR vector in *wiring.c* from `ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)` to `ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)`.

But `delay` doesn't work. What can be the problem?

Comment: I would guess Serial and delay rely on timer 2 and you have just changed it.

Comment: HardwareSerial does not use timers. `delay` uses Timer 0.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *I don't know if millis() and micros() work* - why not? Write a "blink" sketch and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now everything works except for delay()

`delay()` uses `micros()` and `micros()` reads the hardware registers, like this:

```c++
unsigned long micros() {
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;

    cli();
    m = timer0_overflow_count;
#if defined(TCNT0)
    t = TCNT0;
#elif defined(TCNT0L)
    t = TCNT0L;
#else
    #error TIMER 0 not defined
#endif

#ifdef TIFR0
    if ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) && (t < 255))
        m++;
#else
    if ((TIFR & _BV(TOV0)) && (t < 255))
        m++;
#endif

    SREG = oldSREG;

    return ((m << 8) + t) * (64 / clockCyclesPerMicrosecond());
}
```

You would need to change all those references (TCNT0, TIFR0, TOV0 etc.) to use the Timer 2 equivalents.

Comment: This fixed it. Strange that `micros()` works fine without the fix?

Comment: Appeared to work. I'm sure over a longer interval you would have seen anomalies.